# How to invoke a task twice in Thor

Tags: thor

I need to invoke a task twice in Thor. In Rake, this could be accomplished by ["re-enabling"](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Rake/Task/reenable) it, but I can't find an equivalent in either of http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Invocation or https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki/Invocations

Some background, because of old code, sometimes I need to reset a database between tests (I know this is not ideal, but this is *old* code), so my scenario is like

```
desc "all-tests", "all the tests"
def all_tests
  invoke :"clean-db"
  invoke :"first-tests"
  invoke :"clean-db"
  invoke :"second-tests"
end
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331267/call-task-more-than-once-in-rails-3-generator

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation.  What worked for me was calling the methods directly rather than using `invoke`.  For example:

```
class Tests < Thor
  desc('all', 'run all tests')
  def all
    setup()
    invoke :some_test_suite
    teardown()
    setup()
    invoke :some_other_test_suite
    teardown()
    # etc.
  end 

  desc('setup', 'set up the test database')
  def setup
    # some setup tasks here
  end

  desc('teardown', 'tear down the test database')
  def teardown
    # some teardown tasks here
  end
end
```